# How to migrate users from local SQL Server to Azure Active Directory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working on an MVC application and there is no authentication mechanism implemented. We have a user's table in SQL Server and there is no password. I want to migrate the users with a random password to Azure Active Directory.

I came across [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration) article which shows that we can have a json file of users and they can be migrated to Azure Active Directory.

I am unable to achieve this. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The steps you will need to go through on a high level are: 1) Create an app registration in the underlying AAD tenant (step 1.1 in the article), 2) Generate a secret for that app (step 1.2), 3) Grant application permissions for the app to call the Graph API (step 1.3), 4) Write a program that takes the rows from the user table and calls the Graph API to create a user for each row (with .NET you could use the [GraphClient library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/).

Comment: Thanks @juunas 
I have already tried the steps you have mentioned.
I am using [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/scenarios/aadb2c-user-migration) program.

I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: No message. That's the problem.